# img-retina alternative for backgrounds in Bootstrap 4.3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, deprecated

Ref: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/28072

It looks like the `img-retina()` mixin has been deprecated with the suggestion that we should use responsive image tags (I assume this is pictures with source sets?) and object-fit for background images?

Is there a standard/accepted way to replace/replicate the old retina background approach?

This blog post indicates that we should use `position:absolute;` images with source sets?
https://jasonyingling.me/better-performing-background-images-with-object-fit/

However I'm not sure this is suited for a tiled/repeating background image?